# Find changes made on this date

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo from github and found that something interesting happended on this day (X) on this project. I want to see the specific files that changed and what changed in them.

What commands can help we to find that ?

Comment: Have you tried git log  , command??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following options to git log should be useful:

```
   <since>..<until>
       Show only commits between the named two commits. When either <since> or <until> is omitted, it defaults to
       HEAD, i.e. the tip of the current branch. For a more complete list of ways to spell <since> and <until>,
       see gitrevisions(7).
```

as well as

```
   --since=<date>, --after=<date>
       Show commits more recent than a specific date.

   --until=<date>, --before=<date>
       Show commits older than a specific date.
```

additionally i really recommend that you have a look at `git bisect`, described at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search

Comment: Combine this with `--name-only` or `-p` to see the changes.